# IFullTextQuery - exception if there are too may objects

Tags: nhibernate, lucene.net, nhibernate.search

This code works fine:

```
Query query = parser.Parse(expression);

IFullTextSession session = Search.CreateFullTextSession(this.Session);

IFullTextQuery fullTextQuery = session.CreateFullTextQuery(query, new[] { typeof(MappedSequence) });

var l1 = fullTextQuery.List();
```

as long as the query does not return too many objects. If the query contains too many objects the generated sql code is too long and sql server throws an exception. One working solution is to obtain all objects using paging which is fairly slow. Is there a better solution?

Thanks.

C

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I remember correctly, fullTextQuery.List() does a big

```
select ... where ID_COL IN ( id1, id2, id3, id4 ... )
```

where id1, id2 ... are parameters, which number is limited in SQL Server. This way, you get NHibernate entities from lucene documents. Long story short, there is no workaround, except paging.

You can use page size of 1000 elements, if you REALLY need to get this much of data.

Getting 1000's of entities would be slow somewhere : when you display them on screen, for exemple.

Comment: Thanks. I realised this as well. Unfortunately, I have to create an excel sheet given some paramters from a query form post. That's why I have to potentially spew out so many rows.