# NHibernate.Search - SQL Server 2005 - hitting max parameter limit 2100 !

Tags: sql-server-2005, nhibernate.search

I am using NHibernate.Search libraries in my project for free text search. Recently when I started getting more than 2100 results, I started getting max parameter length error from SQL Server.

Does NHibernate.Search take care of such situation ? Any workaround anyone ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could modify NHibernate.Search code to take care of this, or, use custom paging, IE get number of hits for your search, then page nhibernate search results accordingly.

```
public IList<TEntity> Search<TEntity>(Query query, bool? active, string orderBy)
{
    var search = NHibernate.Search.Search.CreateFullTextSession(this.session);

    var total = search.CreateFullTextQuery(query, typeof(TEntity)).ResultSize;

    var first = 0;

    var l = new List<TEntity>();

    while (total > 0)
    {
        l.AddRange(search.CreateFullTextQuery(query, typeof(TEntity))
                .SetFirstResult(first)
                .SetMaxResults(1000)
                .List<TEntity>());

        first += 1000;
        total -= 1000;
    }

    return l;
}
```

See : [IFullTextQuery - exception if there are too may objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5339696/ifulltextquery-exception-if-there-are-too-may-objects)